# jq iterate over a array of values a subset at a time

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have json (that actually starts as csv) of the form of an array of elements of the form:

```
{
    "field1" : "value1"
    "field2.1; Field2.2 Field2.3" : "Field2.1Value0; Field2.2Value0; Field2.3Value0; Field2.1Value1; Field2.2Value1; Field2.3Value1; ..."
}
...
```

I would like to iterate over the string of the field "field2.1; Field2.2 Field2.3", three ";" separated items at a time to produce an array of key value pairs

```
{
    "field1" : "value1"
    "newfield" : [
          { "Field2.1": "Field2.1Value0",
            "Field2.2": "Field2.2Value0",
            "Field2.3": "Field2.1Value0" },
          { "Field2.1": "Field2.1Value1",
            "Field2.2": "Field2.2Value1",
            "Field2.3": "Field2.3Value1"},
          ...
    ]
}
...
```

note that there are actually a couple of keys that need to be expanded like this. Each with a variable number of "sub-keys".

In other words, the original CSV file contains some columns that represent tuples of field values separated by semicolons.

I know how to get down to the "field2.1; Field2.2 Field2.3" and say split it on the ";" but then I'm stuck trying to iterate through that 3 (or however many) items at a time to produce the separate 3 tuples.

The real world example/context is the format of the CSV from catalog export from the Google Play Store.

For example Field2.1 is Locale, Field2.2 is Title and Field3.3 is Description:

```
jq '."Locale; Title; Description" |= split(";") '
```

If possible, then it would be nice if the iteration is based on the number of semicolon separated "subfields" in the key value. There is another column that has a similar format for the price in each country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes the availability of `splits/1` for splitting a string based on a regex. If your jq does not have it, and if you cannot or don't want to upgrade, you could devise a workaround using `split/1`, which only works on strings.

First, let's start with a simple variant of the problem that does not require recycling the headers.  If the following jq program is in a file (say program.jq):

```
# Assuming header is an array of strings,
# create an object from an array of values:
def objectify(headers):
  . as $in
  | reduce range(0; headers|length) as $i ({}; .[headers[$i]] = ($in[$i]) );

# From an object of the form {key: _, value: _},
# construct an object by splitting each _
def devolve:
  if .key|index(";")
  then .key as $key
  | ( [.value | splits("; *")] ) | objectify([$key | splits("; *")])
  else { (.key): .value }
  end;


to_entries | map( devolve )
```

and if the following JSON is in input.json:

```
{
 "field1" : "value1",
 "field2.1; Field2.2; Field2.3" : "Field2.1Value0; Field2.2Value0; Field2.3Value0"
}
```

then the invocation:

```
jq -f program.jq input.json
```

should yield:

```
[
  {
    "field1": "value1"
  },
  {
    "field2.1": "Field2.1Value0",
    "Field2.2": "Field2.2Value0",
    "Field2.3": "Field2.3Value0"
  }
]
```

It might make sense to add some error-checking or error-correcting code.

#### Recycling the headers

Now let's modify the above so that headers will be recycled in accordance with the problem statement.

```
def objectifyRows(headers):
  (headers|length) as $m
  | (length / $m)  as $n
  | . as $in
  | reduce range(0; $n) as $i ( [];
      .[$i] = (reduce range(0; $m) as $h ({};
                 .[headers[$h]] = $in[($i * $m) + $h] ) ) );

def devolveRows:
  if .key|index(";")
  then .key as $key
  | ( [.value | splits("; *")] ) 
  | objectifyRows([$key | splits("; *")])
  else { (.key): .value }
  end;


to_entries | map( devolveRows )
```

With input:

```
{
 "field1" : "value1",
 "field2.1; Field2.2; Field2.3" :
   "Field2.1Value0; Field2.2Value0; Field2.3Value0; Field2.4Value0; Field2.5Value0; Field2.6Value0"
}
```

the output would be:

```
[
  {
    "field1": "value1"
  },
  [
    {
      "field2.1": "Field2.1Value0",
      "Field2.2": "Field2.2Value0",
      "Field2.3": "Field2.3Value0"
    },
    {
      "field2.1": "Field2.4Value0",
      "Field2.2": "Field2.5Value0",
      "Field2.3": "Field2.6Value0"
    }
  ]
]
```

This output can now easily be tweaked along the lines suggested by the OP, e.g. to introduce a new key, one could pipe the above into:

```
.[0] + { newfield: .[1] }
```

#### Functional definitions

Here are reduce-free but efficient (assuming jq >= 1.5) implementations of `objectify` and `objectifyRows`:

```
def objectify(headers):
  [headers, .] | transpose | map( {(.[0]): .[1]} ) | add;

def objectifyRows(headers):
  def gather(n):
    def g: if length>0 then .[0:n], (.[n:] | g ) else empty end;
    g;
  [gather(headers|length) | objectify(headers)] ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm certainly learning a lot going through this solution. The top level parsing works fine.

Comment: I am investigating that the split/parsing seems to be failing/getting confused on some UTF8 input in the field values (Title, Description) though.

Comment: My guess is that an upgrade to the "master" version (on github) would resolve the problem.

Comment: You are correct! Building my own version does not have the splits problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my almost final solution that inserts the new key as well as uses the first element of the ";" list as the key for sorting the array.

```
def objectifyRows(headers):
  (headers|length) as $m
  | (headers[0]) as $firstkey
  | (length / $m)  as $n
  | . as $in
  | reduce range(0; $n) as $i ( [];
      .[$i] = (reduce range(0; $m) as $h ({};
                 .[headers[$h]] = $in[($i * $m) + $h] ) ) )
  ;

def devolveRows:
  if .key|index(";")
  then .key as $multikey
    | ( [.value | splits("; *")] ) 
    # Create a new key with value being an array of the "splits" 
    | { ($multikey): objectifyRows([$multikey | splits("; *")])}
    # here "arbitrarily" sort by the first split key
    | .[$multikey] |= sort_by(.[[$multikey | splits("; *")][0]])
  else { (.key): .value }
  end;

to_entries | map( devolveRows )
```